# Cakephp: How to order list of lastest news use containable model order condition

Tags: cakephp

I have model Book and model Chapter. Their relationship is one Book has many Chapter and each Chapter must belong to one Book.

In controller Books, I want get book info, order by created date of newest Chapter. Problem is they unknown column 'Chapter.created' in 'order clause'. So, how can't I fix it ?

Thanks

```
public function index(){
     $this->paginate = array(
         'contain'=>array(
               'Chapter'=>array(
                    'conditions'=>array('published'=>1,),
                    'order'=>array('ordinal_numbers'=>'desc'),
                    'limit'=>1,
               )
         ),
        'limit'=>8,
        'paramType'=>'querystring',
        'order'=>array('Chapter.created'=>'desc'),
    );
    $this->set('book',$this->paginate());
```

}

Comment: You said your error was related to 'Post.created', yet "Post" is not listed anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed it, it mean is 'Chapter.created'

Comment: you can only get Book with Chapters (ordered) . 
but i suggest to paginate chapters contain Books so you can then get the chapters with their books .

Comment: i think the order clause has to be in contain array.

Comment: Thanks Abdou Tahiri, I got it. Thanks Nouphal.M and Dave ^___^